# Upload de arquivos no sharepoint em uma pasta especifica usando Python

Tags: python, api, upload, file-upload, sharepoint

Estou fazendo upload de arquivo da minha máquina para o sharepoint usando python com a lib [Office-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/), porém só consigo subir o arquivo na raiz do sharepoint e não em uma determinada pasta.
Código que estou utilizando para upload:

```
import os

from settings import settings

from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

ctx = ClientContext.connect_with_credentials(settings['url'],
                                             UserCredential(settings['user_credentials']['username'],
                                                            settings['user_credentials']['password']))

path = "../../../tests/data/SharePoint User Guide.docx"
with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()

list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).rootFolder
name = os.path.basename(path)
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content)
ctx.execute_query()
print("File url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

Com esse código acima, eu consigo fazer upload e os arquivos aparecem na raiz do sharepoint, que no caso chamo de 'Documents'. Então fiz a modificação a seguir para subir em uma determinada pasta, no caso em uma chamada 'Area':

```
list_title = "Documents/Area"
```

Porém, nesse caso já não tenho sucesso, ele retorna que esse caminho de Area não existe. Como posso fazer o upload em uma pasta especifica?

Diretório no meu sharepoint:

[image: Diretório no sharepoint]

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603107/upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-folder-using-python

Comment: @PauloMarques cheguei a ver esse exemplo, porém ele usa outra biblioteca, ele usa a shareplum

Comment: Qual o valor de `target_folder` e de `name`?

Comment: Verifica se tua 'Area' gera um link... Esse link pode servir de path